# Generate a list of difference files using cvs diff command - ignoring CVS tag differences

Tags: compare, branch, diff, cvs

I am trying to generate a list of difference files between two brances of my whole code base.
But i want to exclude those files from list which have 'only' cvs tag differences: Eg

/**
     * This is a responder class for AwaitMatch screen.

```
 *   
 * @author $Author: abxcdefg $
 * @version $Revision: 1.32.60.2 $
 * $Name: bdc-qa-09_04_40-bp $
 * $RCSfile: AwaitMatchResponder.as,v $
 * $Date: 2014/07/02 21:13:36 $
 */
```

I tried following arguments with CVS diff command, it does ignore the CVS tag differences but also 'does' list the name of the file in the output diff file generated. This makes the compare ineffective as almost all the files in project are listed in the poutput file:

cvs diff -w --ignore-matching-lines="*" -r branch1 -w  --ignore-matching-lines="*" -r branch2 > diffs

PS:I want to do some automation and save myself from effort of doing manual comparison of 600+ files in Eclipse/Flash Builder.

Comment: You probably need to use `-kk`. Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7747395/966703